# Liferay Portal 6.2 - How to get theme_display in Web Content Template

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I am trying get the "theme_display" in a Web Content Template (on Liferay Portal 6.2). But it does not work.

```
    #set($serviceContext = $portal.getClass().forName("com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContextThreadLocal").getServiceContext())
    #set($httpServletRequest = $serviceContext.getRequest())
    #set($objThemeDisplay = $httpServletRequest.getAttribute("THEME_DISPLAY"))
```

$themeDisplay

$theme_display

$request.themeDisplay

$request.get("theme-display")

Comment: [This page](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity#section-Access+Objects+from+Velocity-CMS+Templates) may be helpful.

Comment: What errors are you getting?Do these variables display nothing in web content template,as theare available in velocity templates

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `themeDisplay` object in web content templates using `ServiceContextThreadLocal` like so:

Example using: Liferay DXP, freemarker, web content template:

```
<#assign
serviceContextThreadLocal = staticUtil["com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContextThreadLocal"]
themeDisplay = serviceContextThreadLocal.getServiceContext().getThemeDisplay()
/>
```

You will need to ensure you have turned off the restricted variables for templates.

Comment: How do you turn off the restricted variables for templates?

Comment: In Liferay DXP, create a file at `./osgi/config/com.liferay.portal.template.freemarker.configuration.FreeMarkerEngineConfiguration.cfg` with the contents `restrictedVariables=`

Answer (score 0):

themeDisplay object is not available in WC Templates. What do you need it for? Perhaps you can get the same information from Service Locator....

Regards.