# How can it get the theme display in a Web Content template (Liferay 7.x)

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I need to access the theme_display in a Liferay 7.3 Web Content Template.

I tried the following code (from [Liferay Portal 6.2 - How to get theme_display in Web Content Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280046/liferay-portal-6-2-how-to-get-theme-display-in-web-content-template)) but it doesn't work (change in Liferay 7.x) I would guess.

```
<#assign
serviceContextThreadLocal = staticUtil["com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContextThreadLocal"]
themeDisplay = serviceContextThreadLocal.getServiceContext().getThemeDisplay()
/>
```

My goal is to access the login URL dynamically.  I have the following code in my theme which works, but I now need it for some specific content.

```
theme_display.getURLSignIn()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work with just `${themeDisplay.getURLSignIn()}`.
I used it with a dip 7.3
Also the following gist might be helpful: https://gist.github.com/bmvakili/2e83d1b73964d14d873ba5486bc28dd5

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I feel pretty dumb.  That should have been easy to figure out.  And the Gist is very much appreciated.  I was able to replace some old code I had gotten from somewhere to dump variables.  That code stopped working for a lot of the values.  So extra kudos for that!